# Example code on SO for three.js gives a black screen

Tags: support

The Stack Overflow page
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/three.js/info
gives an example code for an animated cube.
I get a black screen on IE11, FF45, and GC49.

By changing the color from 000000 to ffffff,
I see the wire-frame cube.

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true, color: 0xffffff}
```

So I would recommend making that change.

Answer (score 2):

[Done.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5301301/16)

In the future though, you can propose a tag-wiki edit, and it will be reviewed. Leave a descriptive edit reason, and it should be approved.